# add-migration queries the database for the columns I'm trying to add, fails with "Error: Invalid column name 'newColumn1', 'newColumn2', 'newColumn3'"

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to add three columns to an existing table via code first migrations with EF Core (package version 3.1.8). When I run `add-migration <name> -c <context> -o <output folder>`, it's throwing this error (along with a massive stack trace...):

```
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the 
application service provider. Error: Invalid column name 'NewColumn1'.
Invalid column name 'NewColumn2'.
Invalid column name 'NewColumn3'.
Unable to create an object of type 'MyDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at 
design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

Really baffled by this. This is the fourth migration I've added today, none of the previous ones had this issue.

This migration should add the three columns, data for the predefined rows for these columns, and add a default value constraint to `newColumn1`. The column data types:

- `newColumn1`: `bit`, defaults to 0
- `newColumn2`: `nvarchar(50)`
- `newColumn3`: `nvarchar(50)`

My entity before adding my trouble migration:

```csharp
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50), Required]
    public string AttributeName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Required { get; set; }
}
```

This entity changed to the following prior to attempting to add this migration:

```csharp
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50), Required]
    public string AttributeName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Required { get; set; }

    public bool NewColumn1{ get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string NewColumn2 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string NewColumn3 { get; set; }
}
```

In `MyDbContext.OnModelCreating`, I have the following new code:

```csharp
builder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(x => x.NewColumn1).HasDefaultValue(false);
```

The `IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>` has also, as previously mentioned, been updated to have data for all new columns for the predefined rows. No rows exist in the database besides the predefined rows.

I have a theory as to what's going on. I think `add-migration` requires an instance of `MyDbContext`, and when it gets instantiated it verifies that the database looks the way it expects. The context expects the table represented by `MyEntity` to have the three new columns that are defined in the entity, but they don't exist in the database. What I'm curious of is why this just started now? This is my fourth migration of the day, my other migrations added tables, columns, data....why would this just now start becoming an issue?

The msft documentation link in the error makes me think I need to implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>`, configure it in such a way that it makes it not choke. But looking at the behavior of [DbContextOptionsBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder?view=efcore-3.1), it doesn't look like any of the provided options will allow me to bypass the behavior I'm getting.

The database has been updated with all previous migrations, and I checked the DbContextModelSnapshot file...the new columns aren't anywhere in there (as expected). The database I'm targeting is a local SQL Server database.

Comment: EF Core does not perform database verification. There must be some code in service host build chain which tries to query the entity in question. Try running `Add-Migration` with `-Verbose` option, and also enable EF Core logging.

Comment: I have meetings for now, but I think you hit the nail on the head. We're querying the database in ConfigureServices to customer saml/oidc configuration (depending on the customer). The table I'm fighting with now is "SamlAttributeTypes", kinda an enum table for all of our custom attributes. If I comment out the "add saml" method, 'Get-DbContext' suddenly starts working. I had no idea that adding migrations/updating database/getting dbcontexts actually _runs_ some part of the application. The more you know, I guess

Comment: @IvanStoev You know if it's possible to skip certain sections of code if the executor isn't the app itself? I need a way to skip my saml registration code in configureServices if the thing calling ConfigureServices is an EF command...

Comment: Negative. What you can do is to utilize [From a design-time factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation#from-a-design-time-factory) approach, which eliminates the side effect of [From application services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation#from-application-services) approach you are using currently.